# mask not visible when applied

Tags: masking

In my Blender sculpt mode the masked area is not showing up (expected it to show up in black).the overlay is turned out, it still not showing s mask[image]   Can anyone suggest me anything please?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a modifier active that is hiding the mask, like subsurf. Go to the modifier tab and look for this warning:

[image: hidden mask]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your overlays turned off.  Hit Z then select toggle overlays, the background grid and the masking should show up.